# kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Timeout after waiting for 30 secs

Tags: python, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I am using the Kafka producer to publish the message to the Kafka from airflow, I have created pip installable package of producer in the following way

```
class Producer:


def __init__(self):
    self.producer = Producer._create_connection(self)

def _create_connection(self) -> KafkaProducer:
    """
    The code to connect to the bootstrap server.
    :return:
    """
    try:
        producer = KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers=brodker ids,
            retries=some_value,
            api_version=api_version,
            acks=all)
        )
        return producer
    except KafkaError as kafkaerror:
        print(F"connection error {kafkaerror}")
        raise kafkaerror
    except Exception as error:
        print(F"connection error {error}")
        raise error

@staticmethod
def json_serializer(value: str) -> Any:
    """
    JSON Serialiser.
    :param value: value which will be published to kafka
    :return:
    """
    return json.dumps(value).encode(DataLineageConstant.ENCODING)

def send_message(self, **kwargs) -> Dict:
    """
    Method to publish the data to Kafka topic.
    :param kwargs: keyword argument.
    :return: RecordMetada Information.
    """

    # Create the connection
    value = kwargs.get(value)
    key = None

    if value is None:
        raise Exception("No message provided to publish into Kafka")

    try:

        if key in kwargs:
            key = key
            future = self.producer.send(topic_name,
                                        key=key,
                                        value=self.json_serializer(value))
        else:
            future = self.producer.send(topic_name,
                                        value=self.json_serializer(value))

        record_metadata = future.get(timeout=int(30))

        self.producer.flush()
        self.producer.close()
        return record_metadata
    except KafkaError as kafkaerror:
        print(F"connection error {kafkaerror}")
        raise kafkaerror
    except Exception as error:
        print(F"Exception while publishing the message to kafka error {error}")
        raise error
```

calling of the module

```
producer = Producer()
producer.send(value)
```

Please note this is sample code, not exact code. This is similar to actual code.

Here I am publishing thousands of messages every day, only sometimes i am get below error,

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/future.py", line 62, in get
"Timeout after waiting for %s secs." % (timeout,))
```

kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Timeout after waiting for 30 see

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 567, in send
self._wait_on_metadata(topic, self.config['max_block_ms'] / 1000.0)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 694, in _wait_on_metadata
"Failed to update metadata after %.1f secs." % (max_wait,))
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.